# how to update a cell value in sub-second time-series pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I cannot manage to update a cell value when the dataframe index is a sub-second timeseries. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

t0 = '2019-01-05 22:00:00.000'
t1 = '2019-01-05 22:00:05.000'

df_times = pd.date_range(t0, t1, freq = '500L')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['datetime'] = df_times
df['Value']=[20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
df['Target'] = range(len(df_times))
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df
```

will result in this dataframe

[Dataframe contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDhU8.png)

If I try to update a cell 'Target' at index '2019-01-05 22:00:02.000', I end up updating also the 'Target' cell at index '2019-01-05 22:00:02.500'.

[two cells updated instead of one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1ah6.png)

How can I work around this?

Comment: Please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```py
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2019-01-05 22:00:02.000'), 'Target']=57
```

It apparently implicitly casts string to different (less precise) date time than `pandas` version.

Also using `.loc[]` will be better in this case.